# Encounter error 21 with LDAPS in JFROG Artifactory Community Edition for C/C++

Tags: ssl, active-directory, ldap, artifactory

I've installed Artifactory Community Edition for C/C++ 7.9.2 in order to manipulate Conan package.

Everything works fine, except my LDAP**S** configuration: I saw with tcpdump that I encountered **error 21 (Certificate Unknown)**.

I've a AD server in my local network working perfectly fine with an already installed Gitlab (or even with an LDAP browser).

I've followed all the JFrog Documentation that I could find (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/LDAP, https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Managing+TLS+Certificates) but it makes no difference.

I believe the certificate I add in Artifactory configuration isn't found.

I tried two differents ways:

- add the certificate to JVM's trusted Keystore : I've copy my JVM keystore, then added the AD server certificat, and finally passed the result with the option *-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=myPath*
- add the certificate to the *$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/security/keys/trusted* directory.

Is LDAP**S** even supported by the community edition of Artifactory?

Comment: Connecting with SSL to LDAP is a Java feature, not specific to JFrog Artifactory. Check Admin / System Info tab for `java.home` and `JVM arguments` to verify whether your options are in effect and whether you updated Java instance that Artifactory actually uses.

Comment: I've tried to add an extra option when starting Artifactory to the JVM, but it didn't worked. I will look further into it next monday, thanks for your help !

Comment: Ok, so the java.home is correct : `/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/third-party/java`, but the `JVM input arguments` isn't. I've add the option `extraJavaOpts: "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/cacerts"` in my system.yaml, according to Artifactory doc. The cacerts file has correct R/W rights. Maybe I'm missing something ?